# Find IMU's movement direction in x-axis

Tags: imu, accelerometer

I have an IMU device with an accelerometer sensor and I fix that on top of the linear motion rail.so it can only move to the right or left (in the x-axis) side.

How can I determine the direction (right or left) of movement base on the accelerometer's data and relative to the start point? Do I need other sensors' data?

Comment: How many degrees of freedom does the sensor have? Can it slide around the rail as well as along it?

Comment: The imu device has built-in 6 degrees of freedom. But I have attache that with glue on the top of the rail's wagon.

Comment: Have you been able to collect data from the imu moving around? How does it look?

Comment: this device sends accelerometer data in 200hz via wifi connection ( negative and positive float numbers). `How does it look?` I am not sure about your question!

Comment: Have you plotted the data? You should be able to slide your sled up and down the rail then determine the rotation of the sensor using the recorded values. Have you tried doing something like that?